# SQL optimisation Case When (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove "CASE ... WHEN... END" statement and use a CTE or another tips.
Do you you have a better way to do this please ? Or a better request ?

SQL :

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME
       , DATA_TYPE
       , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
       , COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(C.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+C.TABLE_NAME), 
C.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') AS IS_IDENTITY
       , CASE I.IS_PRIMARY WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_PRIMARY
       , case I.IS_FOREIGN WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_FOREIGN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        , OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + 
QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') AS IS_PRIMARY
        , OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + 
QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsForeignKey') AS IS_FOREIGN
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE'
) I ON C.COLUMN_NAME = I.COLUMN_NAME

WHERE C.TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE'
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to remove the CASE *expression*?

Comment: For win time if it's possible

Comment: FYI, the Case statement is not a poor performer. If you are to the point where that specific case statement is the bottleneck, you need to look at hardware.

Comment: Case expressions in WHERE and ON clauses are harder to optimize. But here you have them in the select list, which is no problem at all.

Comment: Ok Thanks all. I will use ISNULL (more readable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ISNULL or COALESCE to make a NULL value default to something else. This eliminates your CASE statement.

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME
       , DATA_TYPE
       , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
       , COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(C.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+C.TABLE_NAME), 
C.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') AS IS_IDENTITY
       , ISNULL(I.IS_PRIMARY,0) AS IS_PRIMARY
       , ISNULL(I.IS_FOREIGN,0) AS IS_FOREIGN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        , OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + 
QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') AS IS_PRIMARY
        , OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + 
QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsForeignKey') AS IS_FOREIGN
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE'
) I ON C.COLUMN_NAME = I.COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: ISNULL/COALESCE are just versions of CASE. Still same execution.

Comment: @BriceChaponneau Yeah, I wouldn't call this an "optimization". It's a perfectly fine way to write it, but no faster or less computationally expensive than CASE/WHEN.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `case` in simple, binary cases I would rather replace

```
CASE I.IS_PRIMARY WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

with

```
IIF(I.IS_PRIMARY = 1, 1, 0)
```

I believe they both work the same as we concern speed but `IIF()` is more human readable...

Answer (score -2):

From what I see here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

indeed the cases are useless. You may remove the

```
case ..... end
```

part from both lines

Comment: This is not for column